# Facebook PHP SDK v5.0 - FacebookRequest not found Error

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using PHP-SDK-v5.0 package [downloaded from here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/5.0.0#install-manually). I am trying to get post-feeds from a public group following an [example provided by facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.4#reading). When I try to run the script, it throws an error - `Fatal error: Class 'FacebookRequest' not found`. Here is the example that throws an error.

```
require_once __DIR__. '/Facebook/autoload.php';    
$request = new FacebookRequest(
      $session,
      'GET',
      '/{group-id}/feed',
      array(
        'fields' => 'full_picture,attachments.limit(3){media,title,type,url},icon,message',
        'limit' => '1'
      )
    );

    $response = $request->execute();
    $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
    var_dump($graphObject);
```

I have another simple facebook login script based on the example below, which **shares the same directory** and works perfectly. So definitely not a path issue.

```
session_start();
require_once __DIR__. '/Facebook/autoload.php';
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => 'xxxxx',
    'app_secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
    ]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$permissions = ['email', 'public_profile', 'user_friends']; // Optional permissions
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://domain.com/fb-app/login-callback.php', $permissions);

echo '<a href="' . htmlspecialchars($loginUrl) . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>';
```

I suspect it is an issue related to namespace of which I am not very familiar. I tried using a solution to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24442149/fatal-error-class-facebookrequest-not-found) question, which suggests to use `use Facebook\FacebookRequest;` but does not work, neither does `$request = new Facebook\FacebookRequest`. Also I feel that the script is incomplete and is supposed to incorporate an access token. I am still learning stuffs, please help me solve this.

Comment: @uri2x I have updated the code with the example but it throws a new error - `Graph returned an error: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.`, any idea ?

Answer (score 3):

You should specifically define the namespace when creating the object:

```
$request = new Facebook\FacebookRequest(...
```

or keep with `new FacebookRequest` but add `use Facebook\FacebookRequset` at the beginning of your script.

Also pay attention that you're using the Facebook SDK v4 syntax instead of v5. See [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookRequest/5.0.0) for information about how to use `FacebookRequest` with SDK v5.

Comment: I had tried that earlier it throws this error - `Fatal error: Call to undefined method Facebook\FacebookRequest::execute()`

Comment: That's a new subject :) That happens because you're probably reading a manual of an outdated SDK - v4 instead of v5. Look [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookRequest/5.0.0) for the latest manual on FacebookRequest.

Comment: Sorry but as I said in my question I have already tried `use Facebook\FacebookRequest;`. it does not work and using `new Facebook\FacebookRequest` throws the above-mentioned additional error.

Comment: @gurung, the undefined method is called because you're not using the SDK correctly. You're trying to use a method from Facebook SDK v4, while you've downloaded Facebook SDK v5. See here how to properly use this class (and don't forget to include autoload.php): https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookRequest/5.0.0

Comment: I have the updated code in the bottom of my question. Please take a look, still throwing an error.

Comment: There's no `->execute()` at all on v5. I suggest you take one of the v5 examples as-is and start from there.

Comment: actually I'm getting the same thing, and these are in fact as described on the 5.0 docs...

Comment: @uri2x https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/ratings/ - these are the 5 docs.. ->execute() is there